# Сделать эффект матового стекла из svg

Tags: css, svg

Всем, привет, подскажите пожалуйста, как наложить svg изображение с эффектом матового стекла на элемент, т.е есть фоновая картинка внизу, а поверх я хочу наложить svg с размытием, пробовал backdrop-filter это свойство работаем по всей высоте и ширине элемента, подскажите, как можно такое реализовать, буду вам благодарен

1 элемент лежит фоном, на этот фон я хочу поставить svg и что бы был blur, можно ли добиться такого эффекта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понятно, на изображениях желаемый вид или что? Размытие на текст тоже должно воздействовать? Покажите, пожалуйста, ДО и ПОСЛЕ, а там уже будет видно какими средствами...

Comment: @Leonid Я думаю, он хочет по принципу `backdrop-filter: blur(...)`, только на фигуру

Comment: Я добавил новую картинку в описание, 1 элемент лежит фоном, на этот фон я хочу поставить svg и что бы был blur

Comment: Можно добиться такого эффекта.

Comment: @Leonid, я с вопросом первый раз на платформе, вы можете помочь решить данную задачу или вы предлагаете помощь за отдельную плату, т.е если можно добиться такого эффекта, как это сделать, что для этого нужно?

Comment: У вас есть само изображение? Вы хотите поверх "поставить" SVG, то есть есть у вас и изображение, переделанное в SVG? В чем вопрос, как сделать SVG полупрозрачным или что? Дайте хоть исходное изображение, оно в PNG? Можно в SVG отрисовать прямоугольник с полупрозрачной завливкой, а изображением воспользоваться как маской для вырезания из этого прямоугольника областей той же формы. Можно сразу воспользоваться комбинацией SVG-фильтров. Можно изображение на canvas отрисовать, изменить свойства (scale, fillStyle, blur) вырезать по границам исходного изображения. Если есть SVG-путь, то все легче.

Comment: @Leonid Вся графика имеется на первом экране , там svg , но у меня не получается достичь такого результата https://www.figma.com/file/Aj25VK6LJiQaN1NPsAov4G/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-1.3)-(Copy)?node-id=0%3A1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Путь (`path`) хранит контур отдельного элемента, отрисованного на 300*300. Поэтому для высоты холста 200 применяется `scale` и `translate` для смещения от края перед `fill(path)`. Перед изменением этих настроек контекст сохраняется (`ctx.save()`), а после восстанавливается - `ctx.restore()`. Потому как в дальнейшем сюда же будет отрисован результат работы на неотображаемом холсте.

Создаем невидимый холст `document.createElement('canvas');`. Сохраняем базовые настройки. Задаем цвет фона (имитация цвета стекла - `fillRect()`). Задаем фильтр для всего (`blur(3px)`), что будет нарисовано в дальнейшем (до восстановления настроек) и переносим изображение основного холста - фигура на нем становится размытой.

Затем настраиваем смещение по координатам и небольшое увеличение будущего куска стекла (можно и вращение добавить). Чтобы сохранить только изображение под стеклом, использую перед его отрисовкой `globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';` - так все предыдущее на холсте сохраниться только там, где будет присутствовать непрозрачные пиксели в дальнейшем. Теперь рисуем фигуру (по умолчанию черную - непрозрачную - `fill(new Path2D(path));`) и размытая фигурка с основного холста и бледный фон проявляется только в месте этой новой фигуры.

Результат работы с невидимым холстом отрисовываем поверх основного: `ctx.drawImage(hidden,0,0);`

```js
const path = "M118 211c-5.88,0.89 -13.66,2 -20,2 -24.3,0 -44,-19.7 -44,-44 0,-24.3 19.7,-44 44,-44 6.92,0 11.95,1.33 18,2 9,1 29,-21 30,-29 0.4,-3.21 0.21,-5.2 -0.01,-5.82 -2.92,-8.14 -6.76,-19.68 -6.76,-28.34 0,-27.61 22.38,-50 50,-50 27.61,0 50,22.39 50,50 0,27.62 -22.39,50 -50,50 -10.27,0 -17.23,-2.84 -25.23,-3.84 -13.24,-1.66 -34,25 -31,32 2.8,6.54 9,16.92 9,27 0,9.96 -4.17,17.36 -8.61,25.12 -7.39,12.88 19.85,34.98 27.41,31.96 3.45,-1.37 7.25,-2.08 11.2,-2.08 17.12,0 31,13.88 31,31 0,17.12 -13.88,31 -31,31 -17.12,0 -31,-13.88 -31,-31 0,-4.74 1.73,-9.5 2.49,-14.02 0.84,-4.92 -10.48,-32.26 -25.49,-29.98z";

const W = 600;
const H = 200;

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = W;
canvas.height = H;

ctx.save();
ctx.scale(0.5,0.5);
ctx.translate(20,40);

ctx.fillStyle = '#f48c38';
ctx.fill(new Path2D(path));
ctx.restore();

const hidden = document.createElement('canvas');
hidden.width = W;
hidden.height = H;
const hctx = hidden.getContext('2d');

hctx.save();
hctx.fillStyle = '#fff6f0';
hctx.fillRect(0,0,W,H);
hctx.filter = 'blur(3px)';
hctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
hctx.restore();

hctx.scale(0.6,0.6);
hctx.translate(-40, -10);
hctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
hctx.fill(new Path2D(path));

ctx.drawImage(hidden,0,0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Чтобы лучше понять, что происходит можно добавить невидимый холст на страницу: `document.body.append(hidden)`.

Comment: спасибо большое за данную реализацию, могу ли я вас чем то большем отблагодарить, чем спасибо?